# Is there a performance cost for the new operator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

In general is there a performance cost for method B:

Method A

```
 var foo = { 
      propertyA:
      ...
 };

 var SomethingSimilarToFoo = { 
      propertyA:
      …
 };
```

Method B

```
Var foo = function(){
       this.propertyA = ..
       …
}

foo1 = new foo(config);
SomethingSimilarToFoo = new foo(config);
```

Comment: Worrying about details like this is generally pointless.

Comment: That's just a guess I assume `Method A` create a `hash` when `Method B` create an `object`. I believe objects cost more than hashes.

Comment: Do you have a `this` context relative to foo available when using `Method A`?

Comment: Creating an instance cost much less then creating a whole new object every time. Think if you had 100 objects vs 100 instances of a single object, it would be Method B unless you have a very small amount of objects. Not to mention how much more code is needed in Method A. You can also use Prototypes if you want better performance.

Comment: Even when you have 100 instances of a single object, you still allocated 100 time the space this object use. Same as creating 100 objects in a row. isn't it ?

Comment: @Micka No, instances can share members.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek to be more specific, methods declared using prototype will be shared. However attributes won't be.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to create an object (like object in POO), with methods, then use `Method B`. However, if you just want a container, like a dictionary/hash, then `Method A` is much sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jsperf.com/methods-vs-instances

On the one hand, it seems that literal objects are much faster than instances on Firefox. Probably, the cause is that function calls are expensive.

On the other hand, instances are faster on some versions of Chrome.

Anyway, using instances without prototype is a bit useless. But using the prototype, instances can inherit properties (which means less memory) and you gain a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Micro benchmarks like this rarely test the thing you are trying to test, especially here   testing language features